# Updating files using AWK: Why do I get weird newline character after each replacement?

Tags: csv, awk

I have a `.csv` containing a few columns. One of those columns needs to be updated to the same number in ~1000 files. I'm trying to use AWK to edit each file, but I'm not getting the intended result.

> What the original `.csv` looks like

```
heading_1,heading_2,heading_3,heading_4
a,b,c,1
d,e,f,1
g,h,i,1
j,k,m,1
```

I'm trying to update column 4 from `1` to `15`.

```
awk '$4="15"' FS=, OFS=, file > update.csv
```

When I run this on a `.csv` generated in excel, the result is a newline `^M` character after the first line (which it updates to `15`) and then it terminates and does not update any of the other columns.

It repeats the same mistake on each file when running through all files in a directory.

```
for file in *.csv; do awk '$4="15"' FS=, OFS=, $file > $file"_updated>csv"; done
```

Alternatively, if someone has a better way to do this task, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Are you running this on Unix, Windows, ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel is generating the control-Ms, not awk. Run dos2unix or similar on your file before running awk on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't reproduce your problem in my linux as writing `15` to last column will overwrite the `\r` (the `^M` is actually 0x0D or `\r`) before the newline `\n`, but you could always remove the `\r` first:

```
$ awk 'sub(/\r/,""); ...' file
```

I have had some issues with non-ASCII characters processed in a file in a differing locale, for example having a file with ISO-8859-1 encoding processed with Gnu awk in UTF8 shell.